# configure junit with maven project

Tags: maven, junit

I have a maven project which has the following pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

And the maven-compiler-plugin mentioned as below :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Whenever i build my project, because of the maven-compiler-plugin , Junit 4.12 version gets installed.

**Question**

I do not want to configure Junit 4.12 since tests run in parallel with Junit 4.12 and this is something which i do not want.

Comment: Unit tests should be isolated from each other, it means running in parallel can't make any harm. If your unit tests don't meet this condition, you should rethink your design instead of looking for a workaround...

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce you case.
maven-compiler-plugin do not have junit in dependencies. It is no way you get Junit 4.12 because of it.

Run `mvn dependency:tree` to see where you get it.